# Rejoining summary statistics onto original data in R

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a data frame with the columns `ID` and `year` (and `value` as well, but this is not of relevance for this question:

```
id    year
1     2006
1     2007
1     2008
2     2007
2     2008
2     2009
2     2010
```

I'd like to add a new column called `minyear`, which is the minimal year for each `id`, displayed on each row:

```
id    year    minyear
1     2006    2006
1     2007    2006
1     2008    2006
2     2007    2007
2     2008    2007
2     2009    2007
2     2010    2007
```

In SQL, I'd do something like `SELECT ID, year, min(year) AS minyear FROM df GROUP BY id`. Is there an `R`-y equivalent which does this in an efficient way?

Comment: See `?ave` - it can compute a summary stat (by default the `ave`rage), and assign it back to every row in a group.

Comment: The dplyr is kind of like the SQL: `library(dplyr) ; df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(minyear = min(year))`

Comment: Same in`data.table`: `require(data.table); setDT(dat); dat[, .(year, minyear = min(year)), by = id]`.